# Laravel apps More companies use this app. Use multiple custom domains with separate databases or a single domain with multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, laravel, server, dns, multi-tenant

I have a question about domains and servers.

I have developed an app in laravel and every company using the app needs its own database of course.

I currently use laravel forge for deployment and use digital ocean for servers.

Every company has its own domain, I was wondering if there was a way to use just one domain example appname.com with the different databases. therefore each log in will be directed to the db it belongs to. Or continue with the different domains ? thanks

Comment: "every company using the app needs its own database of course". Incorrect. You can create a multi-tenant application with one database. Look up "multi-tenant architecture" for ideas. This can involve multiple domains, subdomains, or all in one domain, it's all a matter of preference.

Comment: is it still correct to use multiple subdomains or multiple domains with their respective databases?

Comment: That's entirely your call, and often boils down to product or client preference. It's not going to complicate things technically to any significant degree. Your application can identify what `Host` is being used, and behave accordingly.

Comment: Be *extremely* careful when having "database per client" as that can quickly explode into an unmaintainable mess. It's fine with dozens of clients, but once you cross into hundreds or thousands it's a lost cause. Making even tiny changes will become exponentially harder.

Comment: I think you are talking about the concept: Multitenancy. Basically you enter the main domain, and after login, each "user"(company) gets redirected to their own database. All databases share same architecture but different data.

Comment: so it's better to use different domains or subdomains in order to be more orderly, exactly?